# How to Consolidate Users with the Same Name Under One ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am working with a set of data where there is an ID field and a USERS field. Some Users have the same name but DIFFERENT IDs. I need help consolidating the data set so each user has one unique ID. In the example below, you will see how I consolidate the two Bob Users under a single ID (1). Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

```
**ID         User**
1          Bob 
2          Tom
3          Jim
4          Dan
5          Bob

**ID         User**
1          Bob 
2          Tom
3          Jim
4          Dan
```

Comment: Are you wanting to physically remove the records?  Or just `SELECT` those results?

Comment: Also, what DBMS are you using? (e.g. SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.)

Comment: I apologize for not clarifying. I am using Microsoft SQL Server. I want to physically remove those records. And for the sake of this example, we can call this the USERS table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a CTE and then DELETE from the CTE. Should be quick.

```
/* SETUP */
CREATE TABLE #test (id int identity, user varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #test (user)
VALUES ('bob') , ('Tom') , ('Jim') , ('Dan') , ('Bob')
; 

/* BEFORE */
SELECT * FROM #test ;

/* DELETE QUERY */
WITH fullList AS (
    SELECT id, user
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY user ORDER BY id ) AS rn
    FROM #test
)
DELETE FROM fullList WHERE rn > 1
;

/* AFTER */    
SELECT * FROM #test ;
```

Comment: Siyual beat me to the answer while I was testing. This would be the method I'd use.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using a windowed `ROW_NUMBER` function to identify the first records, and deleting everything else:

```
;With ToDelete As
(
    Select  *,
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By [User] Order By Id Asc) As RN
    From    Users
)
Delete  ToDelete
Where   RN <> 1
```

Comment: In my very humble opinion, outside of good `JOIN` practices, Window Functions are the _BEST_ thing you can learn about in any flavor of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

First Step , to find duplicate records (same id and user)

```
WITH CTE
AS (SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id,User ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber
    FROM #Employees
   )
SELECT * FROM CTE

--DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RowNumber > 1;
```

then change Query to find same users:

```
WITH CTE
AS (SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber
    FROM #Employees
   )
SELECT * FROM CTE
--DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RowNumber > 1;
```